# Using LINQ to group a list of strings based on known substrings that they will contain

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I have a known list of strings like the following:

```
List<string> groupNames = new List<string>(){"Group1","Group2","Group3"};
```

I also have a list of strings that is not known in advance that will be something like this:

```
List<string> dataList = new List<string>()
{
   "Group1.SomeOtherText",
   "Group1.SomeOtherText2",
   "Group3.MoreText",
   "Group2.EvenMoreText"
};
```

I want to do a LINQ statement that will take the dataList and convert it into either an anonymous object or a dictionary that has a Key of the group name and a Value that contains a list of the strings in that group. With the intention of looping over the groups and inner looping over the group list and doing different actions on the strings based on which group it is in.

I would like a data structure that looks something like this:

```
var grouped = new
{
   new
   {
       Key="Group1",
       DataList=new List<string>()
            {
               "Group1.SomeOtherText",
               "Group1.SomeOtherText2"
            }
    },
    new 
    {
       Key="Group2",
       DataList=new List<string>()
            {
               "Group2.EvenMoreText"
            }
    }
    ...
};
```

I know I can just loop through the dataList and then check if each string contains the group name then add them to individual lists, but I am trying to learn the LINQ way of doing such a task.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Just had another idea... What if my group names were in an Enum?

```
public enum Groups
{
    Group1,
    Group2,
    Group3
}
```

How would I get that into a Dictionary>?

This is what I am trying but i am not sure how to form the ToDictionary part

```
Dictionary<Groups,List<string>> groupedDictionary =   (from groupName in Enum.GetNames(typeof(Groups))
                                                      from data in dataList 
                                                      where data.Contains(groupName)
                                                      group data by groupName).ToDictionary<Groups,List<string>>(...NOT SURE WHAT TO PUT HERE....);
```

EDIT 2:

Found the solution to the Enum question:

```
var enumType = typeof(Groups);
Dictionary<Groups,List<string>> query = (from groupName in Enum.GetValues(enumType).Cast<Groups>()
             from data in dataList
             where data.Contains(Enum.GetName(enumType, groupName))
             group data by groupName).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x=> x.ToList());
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That looks like:

```
var query = from groupName in groupNames
            from data in dataList
            where data.StartsWith(groupName)
            group data by groupName;
```

Note that this *isn't* a join, as potentially there are overlapping group names "G" and "Gr" for example, so an item could match multiple group names. If you could extract a group name from each item (e.g. by taking everything before the first dot) then you could use "join ... into" to get a group join. Anyway...

Then:

```
foreach (var result in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Key: {0}", result.Key);
    foreach (var item in result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("  " + item);
    }
}
```

If you *really* need the anonymous type, you can do...

```
var query = from groupName in groupNames
            from data in dataList
            where data.StartsWith(groupName)
            group data by groupName into g
            select new { g.Key, DataList = g.ToList() };
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just updated the question to include enums into the mix and and a strongly typed dictionary as well if you feel up to it :P

Comment: @user867742: I'm afraid I haven't got time to look at that now... but look at using ToLookup instead of ToDictionary.

Comment: @JonSkeet i am struggling to build this up using lambda expression, WOuld you be kind enough to update it with lambda expression as well? thanks

Comment: @kuldeep: I think it would be more appropriate for you to ask a new question showing the query expression you've got, what you've tried using method syntax, and what's going wrong. Then it can be more useful for anyone else trying to perform conversions in the future. (Aside from anything else, there are two different query expressions here, and I don't know which you're interested in...)