# Group List of objects based on substring in one of the fields

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list, substring

I understand this question has already been asked 
[Using LINQ to group a list of strings based on known substrings that they will contain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861256/using-linq-to-group-a-list-of-strings-based-on-known-substrings-that-they-will-c)

But I have a different question.

My code has a list of objects

```
public class Description
{
    public Description();

    public string Desc1 { get; set; }
    public string Desc2 { get; set; }
    public string Desc3 { get; set; }
    public DayMonthYear OriginalDate { get; set; }
    public DayMonthYear PostedDate { get; set; }
}
```

I have a list of these objects and Desc 3 has a card# substring in it. (only for some objects) not all of these have card #.

I have a results object that has a list of description objects . I can easily get the list of descriptions that have card # in those using linq like this.

```
List<Description> CardDescriptions = results.Description.Where(x => x.Desc3.Contains("CARD#")).ToList();
```

But the next part is , the desc 3 field also has the card # (four digits ) after the card #. These might be different card # s , there might be one or more.

Which I am retrieving like this

```
List<String> cardsList = new List<String>();
string[] stringSeparators = new string[] { "CARD#" };

foreach (Description d in CardTrans)
{
    if (d.Desc3.Contains("CARD#"))
    {

        string[] text = d.Desc3.Split(stringSeparators, StringSplitOptions.None);
        if (!(cardsList.Contains(text[1])))
            cardsList.Add(text[1]);
    }
}
```

Is there a way in linq that I can get a list of card# , and their associated List?

Something like this ?

```
List<Tuple<string, List<Description>>>
```

String will be the card # and a list of description objects that I can associate ?

All I need now is how to get the list of String card ids and the entire List that are associated with that card, which means that somehow Linq has to group these objects based on a substring after card ID

Eg

```
Desc 3 : test test test Card#1234
Desc 3 : dsd dsftest Card#1234
Desc 3 : jjjjj iiiiii kkkk Card# 1234
```

Should all be under  "1234" , List of description objects

```
Desc 3 : ujeuejduejtest test Card#9999
Desc 3 : 2323fseff dsftest Card#9999
Desc 3 : sdfsd fsdsdf kkkk Card#9999
```

Should all be under  "9999" , List of description objects

Can Linq do this? Or should I do a foreach loop and add new tuples when ever there is different substring of card#?

Comment: is it possible for you to provide a clean(more real life) example?

Answer (score 3):

```
    List<String> cardsList = new List<String>();
    string[] stringSeparators = new string[] { "CARD#" };

    foreach (Description d in CardTrans)
    {
        if (d.Desc3.Contains("CARD#"))
        {

            string[] text = d.Desc3.Split(stringSeparators, StringSplitOptions.None);
            if (!(cardsList.Contains(text[1])))
                cardsList.Add(text[1]);
        }
    }
```

can be rewritten like this:

```
var cardsList=CardTrans
  .Where(ct=>ct.Desc3.Contains("CARD#"))
  .Select(ct=>ct.Desc3.Split(stringSeparators,StringSplitOptions.None)[1])
  .Disinct();
```

If you want them grouped, then:

```
var cardsList=CardTrans
  .Where(ct=>ct.Desc3.Contains("CARD#"))
  .GroupBy(key=>key.Desc3.Split(stringSeparators,StringSplitOptions.None)[1]);
```

which will result in an `IGrouping<string,Description>`. If you want a tuple, I think this will do it:

```
var cardsList=CardTrans
  .Where(ct=>ct.Desc3.Contains("CARD#"))
  .GroupBy(key=>key.Desc3.Split(stringSeparators,StringSplitOptions.None)[1])
  .Select(x=>Tuple.Create<string,IEnumerable<Description>>(x.Key,x));
```

Test:

```
public class Program
{
   public static void Main(string[] args)
   {
        string[] stringSeparators = new string[] { "CARD#" };
       var CardTrans = new List<Description>()
       {
           new Description(){Desc3="test test test CARD#1234"},
           new Description(){Desc3="dsd dsftest CARD#1234"},
           new Description(){Desc3="jjjjj iiiiii kkkk CARD#1234"},
           new Description(){Desc3="ujeuejduejtest test CARD#9999"},
           new Description(){Desc3="2323fseff dsftest CARD#9999"},
           new Description(){Desc3="sdfsd fsdsdf kkkk CARD#9999"}
       };

        var cardsList=CardTrans
            .Where(ct=>ct.Desc3.Contains("CARD#"))
            .GroupBy(key=>key.Desc3.Split(stringSeparators,StringSplitOptions.None)[1])
            .Select(x=>Tuple.Create<string,IEnumerable<Description>>(x.Key,x));
        cardsList.Dump();
   }
}

public class Description
{
   public Description(){}

   public string Desc1 { get; set; }
   public string Desc2 { get; set; }
   public string Desc3 { get; set; }
   public DayMonthYear OriginalDate { get; set; }
   public DayMonthYear PostedDate { get; set; }
}

public class DayMonthYear{}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: .. I combined both answers and used it.  I cant thank you enough. .. is there a book for linq that you recommend ? I am a new developer and have been learning things directly when I am coding.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any book recommendations.  I'm not much of a book reader myself.  If I have questions, I'd rather just look at the source code (or disassembled source) to find my answers.  It is more often correct that way, lol.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is easy enough using linq, however I've taken a couple of liberties with your question

1. You 3rd example contained `card# 1234` which has an extra space not present in all the other examples. I removed this space to make the question easier to answer.
2. Each of your examples found the card number you wish to group by between `Card#` and the very end of the string. If this is always the case then fine, if it's not you'll need to do more work.

---

The `GroupBy` predicate here is as easy as finding the index of `Card#`, advancing 5 characters, and reading to the end of the string. In the case that the string `Card#` is not present you need to do something else - I've just chosen to return `null`.

```
 var result = items.GroupBy(i => {
            var idx = i.Desc3.IndexOf("Card#");
            if(idx == -1)
                return null;

            return i.Desc3.Substring(idx+5);
        });
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/CJD71521

Comment: Thanks! I think now i understand it better

Answer (score 1):

You can use Regex for this purpose.

```
List<Description> list = new List<Description>();
// ...
var result =
     list.GroupBy(x => Regex.Match(x.Desc3, "CARD# *(\\d{4,4})", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Groups[1].Value)
         .Select(x => Tuple.Create(x.Key, x.ToList()))
         .ToList();

result.RemoveAll(x => x.Item1 == ""); // exclude items without card.
```

Here is the test.

```
List<Description> list = new List<Description>
{
    new Description {Desc1 = "No Card" ,Desc3 = "No Card"},
    new Description {Desc1 = "Des A" ,Desc3 = "ujeuejduejtest test Card#9999"},
    new Description {Desc1 = "Des B" ,Desc3 = " test test test Card#1234"},
    new Description {Desc1 = "Des C" ,Desc3 = "2323fseff dsftest Card#9999"},
    new Description {Desc1 = "Des D" ,Desc3 = " jjjjj iiiiii kkkk Card# 1234"},
};

var result = ...;            

foreach (var tuple in result)
{
    Console.Write("CARD#{0} : ",tuple.Item1);
    foreach (var description in tuple.Item2)
    {
        Console.Write(description.Desc1 + ", ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Outputs:

```
Card#9999 : Des A, Des C,
Card#1234 : Des B, Des D,
```