# Group delimited text by sections using known keys

Tags: c#, string, linq

I've got  string that looks like this.  Every line is `\r` delimited, breaks placed here for visual purposes.

```
BEGIN_SECTIONS_INFORMATION
NUMSECTIONS=6
SECTION_GROUPNAME[1]=GROUP_1
SECTION_NAME[1]=foo
BEGIN_SECTION[1]
//blah...
END_SECTION[1]
SECTION_GROUPNAME[2]=GROUP_2
SECTION_NAME[2]=bazzz
BEGIN_SECTION[2]
//blah...
END_SECTION[2]
END_SECTIONS_INFORMATION
```

I need to split this string by `SECTION_GROUPNAME` into an `IEnumerable<T>` like this:

Index 0:

```
SECTION_GROUPNAME[1]=GROUP_1
SECTION_NAME[1]=foo
BEGIN_SECTION[1]
//blah...
END_SECTION[1]
```

Index 1:

```
SECTION_GROUPNAME[2]=GROUP_2
SECTION_NAME[2]=bazzz
BEGIN_SECTION[2]
//blah...
END_SECTION[2]
```

Rules:

- Every section starts with `SECTION_GROUPNAME[n]`.
- Every section has a `SECTION_NAME[n]` and has an `BEGIN_` and `END_`.
- Section names are unique.

**I have tried:**

```
var sections = from line in sectionGroups
               where line.StartsWith("SECTION_GROUPNAME")
               group line by "SECTION_GROUPNAME";
```

Also tried

```
var sections = sectionGroups.Split(new string[] { "SECTION_GROUPNAME" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861256/using-linq-to-group-a-list-of-strings-based-on-known-substrings-that-they-will-c), OP created enums/list for groups.  I can't do that as I don't know how many groups/sections will be in the string.

Comment: are you only looking for an `IEnumerable<string>` and assume that myEnumerable[n] matches SECTION_GROUPNAME[n], or are you looking to also extract a key from the text? If the latter, what key are you looking for. If the former, why doesn't your split work for you? Can you not just append SECTION_GROUPNAME to the start of each resulting string?

Comment: My split results in everything before `SECTION_GROUPNAME` (the first one, all subsequent ones were not split) and everything after that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want an `IEnumerable<T>` of strings that contain all the content you described without a key structure.

The basic idea is to remove the stuff that you don't want (the beginning and end bits), and then split by the start of your desired string.  In the end, the split text doesn't make it into the array of results, so you have to manually add it back.

The following worked for me:

```
static string s = @"BEGIN_SECTIONS_INFORMATIONNUMSECTIONS=6SECTION_GROUPNAME[1]=GROUP_1SECTION_NAME[1] = foo\rBEGIN_SECTION[1]\rEND_SECTION[1]\rSECTION_GROUPNAME[2]=GROUP_2SECTION_NAME[2] = bazzzBEGIN_SECTION[2]END_SECTION[2]END_SECTIONS_INFORMATION";


static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var withoutEnd = s.Split(new[] {"END_SECTIONS_INFORMATION"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    var SplitItems = withoutEnd[0].Split(new[] { "SECTION_GROUPNAME"}, StringSplitOptions.None).ToList();
    SplitItems.RemoveAt(0); //the first part is just the introduction
    var result = SplitItems.Select(x => "SECTION_GROUPNAME" + x);

}
```